# Can we call every pure solid a crystal?

Tags: solid-state-physics, definition, elements

What are pure solids? How many types of pure solids do we have? Are we still finding new pure solids or are these pure solids limited in number?

Comment: This may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_space_groups. That's just the geometric classification, of course, but it comes as close to your question as one can possibly come, I believe, without going into details of chemistry.

Comment: "Pure" is more of an engineering term than a scientific one.

Answer (score 9):

A pure solid is one which is made up of a single type of atom (e.g. diamond) or a single type of molecule (e.g. ice).  Therefore, the number of pure solids that can exist depends on the number of elements we have in the periodic table.  However, some elements can correspond to more than one type of pure solid.  For example, diamond and graphite are both pure and made entirely out of carbon.  Because we have a finite number of elements, the there must be a theoretical limit to the number of pure solids we can have.  But I believe that we are very far from reaching this limit.  As technology advances, we are able to synthesise even more of them.

Not all solids are crystalline.  In general, solids can be classified as being crystals (has periodic structure), poly crystals (several crystal regions joined together) or amorphous (no periodic structure).

Comment: How many crystal did we find tell now?
where can find it's updated list.

Comment: This isn't quite right. 'Pure' means no contaminants, not simply a single atom or molecule type. For example, calcium carbonate. It's also worth noting that many of the newly synthesised solids are only stable under extreme conditions, like very high pressures.

Comment: "Because we have a finite number of elements, the there must be a theoretical limit to the number of pure solids we can have" -- well, if there's a finite limit to the number of atoms in a molecule. Which in principle there isn't. To further complicate things, when we talk about a pure polymer we don't mean that every molecule is identical. Any theoretical limit is larger than we could conceivably reach before the heat death of the universe :-)

Comment: where can  i know how far our theoretical limit has gone up to yesterday .
There must be some principle behind this.
can any one tell me the number of pure solid's we found till yesterday with there names?
so that i can compare them with my analysis?

Comment: @SteveJessop even this is excluding the possibility of isomers (different molecules made of the same set of atoms)